# Is it possible to recursively chip an Eigen Tensor based on the values specified in an array?

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen, tensor, eigen3

I am trying to create a wrapper around an `Eigen::Tensor` object in c++. The idea is to create a chipped view on a Tensor based on a provided array, which either specifies the row along which to chip or a `-1` to signify to skip the chipping operation for this dimension:

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> tensor(4, 3, 2);
std::vector<int> indices = {3, -1, 1};
```

The desired result would be the same as doing

```
auto view = tensor.chip(1, 2).chip(3, 0)
```

To get the first row in the last dimension and the third row in the first dimension.
(See the [documentation of chip](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html) in the Eigen::Tensor documentation)

My initial approach was to simply use a loop:

```
template<typename T, int N>
auto createChippedAndSlicedView(Eigen::Tensor<T, N>& tensor, const Indices<N>& indices) {
    auto view = tensor;
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (indices.chip_indices[i] != -1) {
            view = view.chip(indices.chip_indices[i], i);
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

But this doesn't work, since we are changing the dimensionality of what we are trying to assign to `view` at each iteration where we try to chip. I then tried to implement it recursively:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename TensorType>
auto chipTensorRecursive(TensorType &tensor, const std::vector<int> &indices, size_t dim) {
    if (dim >= indices.size()) {
        return tensor;
    }
    if (indices[dim] == -1) {
        return chipTensorRecursive(tensor, indices, dim + 1);
    } else {
        auto chippedTensor = tensor.chip(indices[dim], dim);
        return chipTensorRecursive(chippedTensor, indices, dim + 1);
    }
}
template<typename TensorType>
auto chipTensor(TensorType &tensor, const std::vector<int> &indices) {
    return chipTensorRecursive(tensor, indices, 0);
}
int main() {
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> tensor(4, 3, 2);
    std::vector<int> indices = {1, -1, 1};
    tensor.setValues({{{ 0,  1}, { 2,  3}, { 4,  5}}, 
                      {{ 6,  7}, { 8,  9}, {10, 11}}, 
                      {{12, 13}, {14, 15}, {16, 17}}, 
                      {{18, 19}, {20, 21}, {22, 23}}});
    auto result = chipTensor(tensor, indices);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this generates an internal eigen error

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:72,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorInitializer.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::internal::Initializer<Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> > > > >, -893>’:
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorInitializer.h:29:53:   recursively required from ‘struct Eigen::internal::Initializer<Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> > > > >, -2>’
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorInitializer.h:29:53:   required from ‘struct Eigen::internal::Initializer<Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> > > > >, -1>’
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h:1006:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::TensorBase<Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> > > > >, 1>’
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorChipping.h:80:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> > > > >’
test.cpp:19:35:   recursively required from ‘auto chipTensorRecursive(TensorType&, const std::vector<int>&, size_t) [with TensorType = Eigen::TensorChippingOp<-1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> >]’
test.cpp:19:35:   required from ‘auto chipTensorRecursive(TensorType&, const std::vector<int>&, size_t) [with TensorType = Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>]’
test.cpp:25:31:   required from ‘auto chipTensor(TensorType&, const std::vector<int>&) [with TensorType = Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>]’
test.cpp:42:29:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorInitializer.h:29:53: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
   29 |     typename Initializer<Derived, N - 1>::InitList> InitList;
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Stating that it has reached the maximum limit for templates that can be created. According to my understanding, the compiler should try to create an instance of the `chipTensorRecursive` template method for each dimensionality up to the maximum specified one, which in this case is three. Why are there so many instances that are created instead?
Would this be considered a clean approach to the abovementioned problem?
[The code can be run in the compiler explorer here](https://godbolt.org/z/7orK7rc14)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose because N was not being reliably decremented in this implementation, which caused the compiler to create infinitely many instances of our recursiveChip function. Reducing the input array to only contain the dimensions alongside which to chip fixed the issue:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename TensorType, size_t N, size_t M=N>
auto chipTensorRecursive(TensorType &tensor, const std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> &chips) {
    if constexpr (M == 0) {
        return tensor;
    } else {
        int dim = chips[M - 1].first;  // Use N-1 as index
        int row = chips[M - 1].second;

        auto chippedTensor = tensor.chip(row, dim);
        return chipTensorRecursive<decltype(chippedTensor), N, M-1>(chippedTensor, chips);
    }
}

template<typename TensorType, size_t N>
auto chipTensor(TensorType &tensor, const std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> &chips) {
    return chipTensorRecursive<TensorType, N>(tensor, chips);
}

int main() {
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> tensor(4, 3, 2);
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 2> chips = {{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}};
    tensor.setValues({{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}},
                      {{6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11}},
                      {{12, 13}, {14, 15}, {16, 17}},
                      {{18, 19}, {20, 21}, {22, 23}}});
    auto result = chipTensor(tensor, chips);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```